# How can I call 3 .mar files in my pipeline?

Tags: python, pipeline, torchserve

I'm working on a program that will eventually split into 3 .mar files and some other functions.
I was wondering:

1. Should I do an specific type of preprocess or how it will be different from calling functions?
2. How can I call these 3 .mar files?